# How to align rows in a DIV layout?

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to get rid of tables from an old project, but I found a problem I don't know how to resolve. If I have a table like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/a4FLQ/):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>First Row</td>
        <td>Second Row</td>
        <td>Third Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Some content here
        </td>
        <td>
Lorem ipsum ad his scripta blandit partiendo, eum fastidii accumsan euripidis in, eum liber hendrerit an. Qui ut wisi vocibus suscipiantur, quo dicit ridens inciderint id. Quo mundi lobortis reformidans eu, legimus senserit definiebas an eos. Eu sit tincidunt incorrupte definitionem, vis mutat affert percipit cu, eirmod consectetuer signiferumque eu per. In usu latine equidem dolores. Quo no falli viris intellegam, ut fugit veritus placerat per.
        </td>
        <td>
            Problem comes when columns have different content height
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>This is aligned!</td>
        <td>With this</td>
        <td>And this!!</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Lastest rows in each column are aligned. How to do this in a DIV layout design? My attempt was [this](http://jsfiddle.net/a4FLQ/1/), but it doesn't work as I expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Pavel. I still prefer getting rid of tables for non-tabular data (it's a thin line what's tabular data and what's not, but I'd not personally consider this so... I guess it depends on how much content you have).

I would use lists. Divs are good too, but lists are easier to style (you don't necessary have to give them classes). Also, if you are switching from tables to divs, it's a very good thing to get a grip on lists, you'll be using them a lot. Just a different option.

**Edit**: Here's more infor about using lists for tabular data. Source: http://mirificampress.com/permalink/the_amazing_li

**Multi-column Lists with `li`**

Building lists that wrap into multiple columns is quick and easy with `li`. When data is actually tabular (requiring column header, columns, and rows), you should use a `table`. But when you're just looking to spice up the look of a list and make it a little easier to read, you should use this method. Just like any other set of `li`s, multi-column lists make for simple HTML code and easy rearranging of list items. Here's how it works.

HTML:

```
<div id="list_wrapper">
    <ul class="multiple_columns">
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Three</li>
        <li>Four</li>
        <li>Five</li>
        <li>Six</li>
        <li>Seven</li>
        <li>Eight</li>
        <li>Nine</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
ul{
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}

/* The wider the #list_wrapper is, the more columns will fit in it */
#list_wrapper{
    width: 200px
}

/* The wider this li is, the fewer columns there will be */
    ul.multiple_columns li{
        text-align: left;
        float: left;
        list-style: none;
        height: 30px;
        width: 50px;
    }
```

The list items just stack against each other horizontally until they fill the width of the containing wrapper. In this case we have a wrapper that is 200px wide and each list item is set to 50px wide. Since 50 goes into 200 four times, that means we'll have four list items in each row.

Give it a try and come back if you have any specific questions :)

Comment: It's possible an example.. I'm not very good with HTML and CSS :)

Comment: @Ivan done. Practise playing with this code to understand how the list works. Also, for future reference, check documentation about using lists for menus, it'll save you a lot of time for next projects :) Welcome to the awesome world of non-tables!

Answer (score 3):

Don't make things so complicated. If you want your data have a table look then why getting rid of table? Table layout is bad when designing the whole pages. But if you need its features think again about your decision.

Having said that, if you want align some elements horizontally then why putting them in separate divs? Put them in one div and remove "float" style on divs, so they come under each other.

Comment: Well, this is a page feature, it is, all pages will have this layout so I believe it's poor to use tables. When I putted in the same DIV then columns were missaligned :( Could you modify the jsfiddle to show me how to do it? Thanks

Comment: @Ivan if you have elements that should be aligned horizontally and vertically at the same time, then I think trying some unnatural styles and layout tweaking just for the sake of removing tables is greater evil than just simply using tables. So sorry I really don't know *good* way to implement your idea with div.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use containers as rows, and not as collumns.